# Understanding buffer Behavior with flowOn in Kotlin Flow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I'm working with Kotlin Flow in my project and I've noticed a behavior that seems like implicit buffering of values, even though I haven't explicitly used the buffer operator. I can't understand why use buffer if i can use flowOn? whats dffirence between flowOn and buffer?

```
fun withoutBuffer() = runBlocking {
    val flow = flow<Int> {
        repeat(50) {
            println("emit $it")
            emit(it)
        }
    }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)

    flow.collect {
        println("collect $it")
        delay(500)
    }
}
```

result:
emit 0
emit 1
emit 2
emit 3
emit 4
emit 5
emit 6
emit 7
emit 8
emit 9
emit 10
emit 11
emit 12
emit 13
emit 14
emit 15
emit 16
emit 17
emit 18
emit 19
collect 0
collect 1
collect 2
collect 3
collect 4
collect 5
collect 6 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the docs for [flowOn](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flow-on.html).

> Otherwise, if changing dispatcher is required, it collects flow emissions in one coroutine that is run using a specified context and emits them from another coroutines with the original collector's context using a channel with a default buffer size between two coroutines similarly to buffer operator, unless buffer operator is explicitly called before or after flowOn, which requests buffering behavior and specifies channel size.

You have to explicitly do `.buffer(0)` on your flow to specify non-default buffering behaviour. (I'd prefer if this wasn't the case but it's what the docs say. Anything for operator fusion I guess)